# How to get immediate parent node with scrapy in python?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler, parent-child

I am new to **scrapy**. I want to crawl some data from the web. I got the html document like below.

```
dom style1:
<div class="user-info">
    <p class="user-name">
        something in p tag
    </p>
    text data I want
</div>

dom style2:
<div class="user-info">
    <div>
        <p class="user-img">
            something in p tag
        </p>
        something in div tag
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="user-name">
            something in p tag
        </p>
        text data I want
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the data **text data I want**, now I can use **css** or **xpath** **selector** to get it by check it exists. But I want to know some better ways.
For example, I can get css `p.user-name` first, and then I get **it's parent**, and then I get it's `div/text()`, and always the data I want is the `text()` of the `p.user-name`'s immediate parent `div`, but the question is, how can I get the immediate parent `p.user-name`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With xpath you can traverse the xml tree in every direction(parent, sibling, child etc.) where css doesn't support this.
For your case you can get node's parent with xpath `..` parent notation:

```
//p[@class='user-name']/../text()
```

Explanation:
`//p[@class='user-name']` - find `<p>` nodes with class value `user-name`.
`/..` - select node's parent.
`/text()` - select text of the current node.

This xpath should work in both of your described cases.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `following-sibling` axis?

```
>>> s = scrapy.Selector(text='''<div class="user-info">
...     <p class="user-name">
...         something in p tag
...     </p>
...     text data I want
... </div>''')
>>> username = s.css('p.user-name')[0]
>>> username.xpath('following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
'\n    text data I want\n'
>>> 

>>> s2 = scrapy.Selector(text='''<div class="user-info">
...     <div>
...         <p class="user-img">
...             something in p tag
...         </p>
...         something in div tag
...     </div>
...     <div>
...         <p class="user-name">
...             something in p tag
...         </p>
...         text data I want
...     </div>
... </div>''')
>>> username = s2.css('p.user-name')[0]
>>> username.xpath('following-sibling::text()[1]').get()
'\n        text data I want\n    '
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, but the dom is much more complicated than I give.