# scrapy get parent element

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and need to do one thing. I used to use lxml and did

```
elements = careers.xpath('//text()[contains(., "engineer")')
```

After that I was able to do

```
element = elements[0].getparent()
```

Unfortunately, I can't do the same with `scrapy`.

I try doing

```
response.xpath('//text()[contains(., "engineer")')
```

as well as `.getparent()` from any of these elements, but it says that Selectors have no attribute `getparent`. Is it possible to do the same with `scrapy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the parent element, you can use the `..` notation at the end of your XPath expression. Consider reading this other [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418499/7663649) for more details.

Apart from that, you may want to add a closing `]` at the end of your XPath to close the `[` before `contains`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot